# NodeJS Await Within Await Unexpected Token

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, async-await

I am working on a basic function inside of AWS Lambda, running on NodeJS. At the portion of the code I've tagged, the development environment is giving me an error saying `Parsing error: Unexpected token tieDown()`

If I remove the `await` portion the error disappears, however it is not possible to remove this because I obviously need to WAIT for that function to finish and return an object before it can begin breaking it down.

As you can see the main handler is already `async`, and the first `await`/`promise` portion works perfectly. So why is this failing?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'});
  exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const rDom = event.referring_domain;
    const sIP = event.source_ip;
    const uA = event.user_agent;
    
    // THIS AWAIT WORKS FINE
    await checkDomain().then(data => {
     if(isEmpty(data)){
      let _response = {
        statusCode: 403,
        body: "Permission denied"
       };
       console.log("Perm denied");
      return _response;
     }else{
        // ERROR HERE!!!
        await tieDown().then(data =>{
         
        });
     };
     
     }).catch((err) => {
     console.error(err);
    });
    
  };
  
 function checkDomain(rDom){
  const params = {
   
   Key : {
     "domain" : "sample.com"
   },
   TableName: "myTable"
  };
  return ddb.get(params, function(err, data){
   if (err) console.log(err.stack);
  }).promise();
 }
 
 function isEmpty(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function tieDown(sIP, uA){
 const userQuery = {
       Key : {
         "ip" : "192.168.0.1",
         "ua" : "blah"
       },
       TableName: "Table2"
      };
  return ddb.get(userQuery, function(err, data){
   if (err) console.log(err.stack);
  }).promise();
}
```

This is my first time every working with NodeJS/Lambda/DynamoDB so all help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: This is not a duplicate. They are getting a SyntaxError not the "await is not valid in async function"

Comment: @LoganDevine it's the same issue. There's a nested function in Ethan's sample, which is not async. Ethan, take the time to learn about Promises and how async/await relates to them. Having both `await` and `.then()` on a single line means you fundamentally misunderstand how they work together.

Comment: @Evert: The error would be different usually?

Comment: @Evert I suppose this was not the best tutorial to learn from then? Even though she is a doctor, https://youtu.be/f7o8RV3Edck?t=859 (regarding `await` and `then` on a single line)

Comment: @LoganDevine could just be a different javascript engine or different contexts throwing different kinds of errors. Fundamentally the problem is the same, even if the literal error message is different.

Comment: @Ethan, I can't really give you a great recommendation for a tutorial. My take on this is that authoritative documentation like MDN tend to be better sources than youtube videos, but different people learn in different ways.